# Probability of a unknown distribution $F$ is $1/n!$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that $$X_1, ... , X_n \sim F$$ and that all $X_i$ are i.i.d. and $F$ is assumed to be a continuous distribution. Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $n$ elements. 
Why is it that then $$\mathbb{P}(X_{\pi(1)}<X_{\pi(2)} < \cdots < X_{\pi(n)})=\frac{1}{n!}?$$
This came up in context to Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney-Test.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There are $n!$ permutations, each order is equally probable.

Comment: Oh and the sets $\Omega_{\pi}=\{\omega | X_{\pi(1)}(\omega) < \cdots<X_{\pi(1)}(\omega)\}$ are disjoint for different $\pi \in S_p$, where $S_p$ is the permutation group with $p$ elements. And we also have that $\Omega = \bigcup_{\pi \in S_p}^{} \Omega_\pi$. Right? But why are they equally probable?

Comment: Yes.  That's where this breaks down for discrete distributions (or distributions with atoms).  In that case you'd have non-zero probabilities for cases with equality.

Comment: They are equally probably by symmetry.  Permutations are measure preserving (as your variables are identically distributed).

Comment: What do you mean by measure preserving? I took a measure theory class this semester, but without any probability theory.

Comment: Ok, then density preserving.  Suppose $\phi(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ is the density function for the joint distribution.  then $\phi$ is symmetric in the variables (almost surely...meaning that the points on which the translates differ have probability $0$).

Comment: Think this through for discrete distributions.  It follows from the i.i.d. assumption.

Comment: For having a picture associated with this equiprobability, consider the permutohedron (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron): all vertices are equivalent...